# unable to update cookies using jquery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a asp.net web page that is using cookies to update search filter results.  I am using a checkbox list populated with different categories like sports, music, food, etc. and with a jquery on change event I use the jquery and JavaScript to write an index and category ID to the cookies.  It builds a multi-valued cookie similar to "1=26&2=14" depending on how many check boxes are selected. Then on post-back the C# code reads in the cookies to update the search filter and search results. This is working just fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.  But for some reason it is not working in IE 10.  I can not figure out what I am doing wrong and any help is appreciated.  Here is the jquery event:

```
    $('.cbl-eventSearchAdv-category input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    var index = 1;
    var cookieString= "";
    $('.cbl-eventSearchAdv-category input[type="checkbox"]').not(':first').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            cookieString += index + "=" + $(this).val() + "&";
            index++;
        }
    });
    var newCookieString = cookieString.slice(0, -1);
    document.cookie = "CategoriesSelectedEvents=" + newCookieString + "; expires=;  path=/";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that IE does not allow empty `expires` property. According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), if the property is not set, cookie will last till the end of session. So I think this should work as expected:

```
document.cookie = "CategoriesSelectedEvents=" + newCookieString + "; path=/";
```

Also I would suggest using [jQuery.cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin for cross-browser work with cookies.

Comment: Ilya Luzyanin, appreciate the quick response.  I went back and removed all the "expires=;" and everything is working across all browsers.  Thanks again.